# How to play a SRT (Secure Reliable Transfer) in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, srt

I was wondering if it's possible to play a video using the Secure Reliable Transfer protocol. Videos of this type start with `srt://`. I know that VideoView only supports https and another protocol I don't remember but not srt.

Any attempt at googling this yields results concerning srt subtitle files, which isn't what I am looking for.

Does anyone know how one might play an srt video on android?

Comment: Do you have any way to get these SRT bytes in Android? Maybe read the bytes into an Array (a buffer) then send buffer to videoView? This would meaning reading the whole video into memory then play from there. Once it works for a short (5 second) clip, you can try other formats like fragmented MP4 or maybe TS to load/play in pieces as they come in from SRT server.

Comment: Did you find any better way or came across the Larix Player? Works fine for me playing back a live stream. I'm now looking for a solution to automatically launch the stream at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes here looking for an answer, here's what I did to get it working. My approach was for a live stream but it can be modified to work with single file type videos.

I managed to implement a custom ExoPlayer DataSource that works with live streaming SRT.

[Uses srtdroid library](https://github.com/ThibaultBee/srtdroid)

#### Factory

```
class SrtLiveStreamDataSourceFactory(
    private val srtUrl: String,
    private val port: Int,
    private val passPhrase: String? = null
) :
    DataSource.Factory {
    override fun createDataSource(): DataSource {
        return SrtLiveStreamDataSource(srtUrl, port, passPhrase)
    }
}
```

#### DataSource

```
const val PAYLOAD_SIZE = 1316


class SrtLiveStreamDataSource(
    private val srtUrl: String,
    private val port: Int,
    private val passPhrase: String?

) :
    BaseDataSource(/*isNetwork*/true) {

    private var socket: Socket? = null
    private val byteQueue: Queue<Byte> = LinkedList()


    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec): Long {
        socket = Socket()
        socket?.setSockFlag(SockOpt.TRANSTYPE, Transtype.LIVE)
        socket?.setSockFlag(SockOpt.PAYLOADSIZE, PAYLOAD_SIZE)
        if(passPhrase != null){
            socket?.setSockFlag(SockOpt.PASSPHRASE, passPhrase)
        }
        socket?.connect(srtUrl, port)
        return C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
    }


    /**
     * Receives from SRT socket and feeds into a queue. Depending on the length requested
     * from exoplayer, that amount of bytes is polled from queue and onto the buffer with the given offset.
     *
     * You cannot directly receive at the given length from the socket, because SRT uses a
     * predetermined payload size that cannot be dynamic
     */
    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray, offset: Int, length: Int): Int {
        if (length == 0) {
            return 0
        }
        var bytesReceived = 0
        if (socket != null) {
            val received = socket!!.recv(PAYLOAD_SIZE)
            for (byte in received.second /*received byte array*/) {
                byteQueue.offer(byte)
            }
            repeat(length) { index ->
                val byte = byteQueue.poll()
                if (byte != null) {
                    buffer[index + offset] = byte
                    bytesReceived++
                }
            }
            return bytesReceived
        }
        throw IOException("Couldn't read bytes at offset: $offset")
    }

    override fun getUri(): Uri? {
        return Uri.parse("srt://$srtUrl:$port")
    }

    override fun close() {
        socket?.close()
        socket = null
    }
}
```

#### Simple usage

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        val url = SRT_URL_HERE (exclude srt://)
        val port = PORT_HERE

        val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
            SrtLiveStreamDataSourceFactory(
                url,
                port,
            ),
        ).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.EMPTY))


        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .build()
        player.setMediaSource(source)
        binding.playerView.player = player


        player.prepare()
        player.play()
        player.playWhenReady = true

    }
}
```