# How to play a SRT (Secure Reliable Transfer) in android? But in mode listener

Tags: android, kotlin, video-streaming

im new in StackOverflow, so please apologies if my content is not as expected. Also i'm not native english person so apologize too my grammar mistakes. In addition i'm starting to learn Android and Kotlin so please don't take in account my poorly knowledge

Looking for this question: [How to play a SRT (Secure Reliable Transfer) in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788480/how-to-play-a-srt-secure-reliable-transfer-in-android) i've been able to receive a str video stream from my computer, which records the screen and streams it from OBS. It needed a little fixes two years later, but actually works!

The problem is it only works if OBS streammer SRT url mode is set to listener (e.g.: srt://192.168.0.x:PORT?mode=listener)

I would like my computer to stream SRT in caller mode so i can define the maxlatency (e.g.: srt://192.168.0.X:PORT?mode=caller&latency=1000000&transtype=live) and my Android phone to receive the str stream in listener mode

May someone help me to archieve this goal?

Thanks a lot! if necessary, i can create a public repository with the Android Studio project if someone can also help me with license stuff

I tried this: [How to play a SRT (Secure Reliable Transfer) in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788480/how-to-play-a-srt-secure-reliable-transfer-in-android)