# Build a srt video stream project using srtdroid library in Android Studio

Tags: android

refering to:

[How to play a SRT (Secure Reliable Transfer) in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788480/how-to-play-a-srt-secure-reliable-transfer-in-android)

I can't compile my project without errors

there are several errors

I tried to create a project in android studio as recommended by Dr BigKitkat.
I create an "Empty views activity" with Kotlin language.
I insert srtdroid library in the dependency "Mave central ver. 1.5.2"
I insert exoplayer library "com.google.android.exoplayer 2.19.0"
I copied your factory code and Datasource code at begin of file and simple usage as replace to main activity default.

When I build the project I have several errors: the first "Unresolved reference: DataSource"

where am I wrong? ........certainly many times :)

Please Dr BigKitkat help me ...

this is my code :

```kotlin
package com.example.play_srt

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class SrtLiveStreamDataSourceFactory(
    private val srtUrl: String,
    private val port: Int,
    private val passPhrase: String? = null
) :
    DataSource.Factory {
    override fun createDataSource(): DataSource {
        return SrtLiveStreamDataSource(srtUrl, port, passPhrase)
    }
}

const val PAYLOAD_SIZE = 1316


class SrtLiveStreamDataSource(
    private val srtUrl: String,
    private val port: Int,
    private val passPhrase: String?

) :
    BaseDataSource(/*isNetwork*/true) {

    private var socket: Socket? = null
    private val byteQueue: Queue<Byte> = LinkedList()


    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec): Long {
        socket = Socket()
        socket?.setSockFlag(SockOpt.TRANSTYPE, Transtype.LIVE)
        socket?.setSockFlag(SockOpt.PAYLOADSIZE, PAYLOAD_SIZE)
        if(passPhrase != null){
            socket?.setSockFlag(SockOpt.PASSPHRASE, passPhrase)
        }
        socket?.connect(srtUrl, port)
        return C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
    }


    /**
     * Receives from SRT socket and feeds into a queue. Depending on the length requested
     * from exoplayer, that amount of bytes is polled from queue and onto the buffer with the given offset.
     *
     * You cannot directly receive at the given length from the socket, because SRT uses a
     * predetermined payload size that cannot be dynamic
     */
    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray, offset: Int, length: Int): Int {
        if (length == 0) {
            return 0
        }
        var bytesReceived = 0
        if (socket != null) {
            val received = socket!!.recv(PAYLOAD_SIZE)
            for (byte in received.second /*received byte array*/) {
                byteQueue.offer(byte)
            }
            repeat(length) { index ->
                val byte = byteQueue.poll()
                if (byte != null) {
                    buffer[index + offset] = byte
                    bytesReceived++
                }
            }
            return bytesReceived
        }
        throw IOException("Couldn't read bytes at offset: $offset")
    }

    override fun getUri(): Uri? {
        return Uri.parse("srt://$srtUrl:$port")
    }

    override fun close() {
        socket?.close()
        socket = null
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        val url = "www.example.com" /*SRT_URL_HERE (exclude srt://)*/
            val port = 512

        val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
            SrtLiveStreamDataSourceFactory(
                url,
                port,
            ),
        ).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.EMPTY))


        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .build()
        player.setMediaSource(source)
        binding.playerView.player = player


        player.prepare()
        player.play()
        player.playWhenReady = true

    }
}
```